# read directory in react native scoped storage

Tags: android, react-native, scoped-storage

I am following this package `https://github.com/ammarahm-ed/react-native-scoped-storage` in my react native project . I have one question related to this package that in its official documentation there is a method to read files but how to read whole directory with that package . I did give permission with that code `const permission = await ScopedStorage.openDocumentTree(true);` but as this package react-native-fs provide a way to read folder like that `await RNFS.readDir(directory);` how to achieve this with the help of `react-native-scoped-storage`

Comment: any solution?  im curious i also want to implement same functionality